# check if oracle function exists

Tags: .net, sql, oracle

I have an Oracle schema, where I have some functions and some packages that have functions inside.

How can I test if a string value is a function name in my schema, and if it is, return the function result, or if it's not a function to return the string value?

I tried to start from

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','PACKAGE','PACKAGE_BODY')
```

but this does not return the function names from inside the packages.
Thank you!

Comment: How about the arguments to the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the view [ALL_PROCEDURES](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2025.htm).

The column OBJECT_NAME will show you the name of standalone functions and procedures, and packages names.  The column PROCEDURE_NAME will show you the names of functions and procedures inside a package.

As you're only interested in functions you might be better off using [ALL_ARGUMENTS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1014.htm#i1573843). This views records the parameters used by a procedure or function.  If a given program unit has a POSITION with a value of zero, that indicates the return value for a function.